# Installing gnu-tar without brew

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am trying to install gnu-tar based on a tutorial guide I am following. However, I am facing some issues having the installing using the following command `brew install gnu-tar --with-default-names`)

The laptop I have to install it on belongs to the company and I am not given root access to perform sudo commands (however, I am granted administrative rights or it).

Is there an alternative way to install gnu-tar without brew or anything that requires sudo?

Comment: @LangLangC I am running Sierra. I found a solution to install homebrew locally - https://superuser.com/questions/619498/can-i-install-homebrew-without-sudo-privileges. However, I am getting some other errors after successfully installing my required packages. Not sure if they are related.

Comment: Then please update your Q with an **[edit]** to include the new information from these comments and your findings. (Comments are volatile)

Answer (score 1):

Get [GNU Tar](http://rudix.org/packages/tar.html) from [Rudix](http://rudix.org).

You don't need to use Rudix's command-line tool. Just download a pkg from [GNU Tar](http://rudix.org/packages/tar.html) and open it. This will install GNU Tar in /usr/local.

Comment: The given Link to download GNU Tar does not work anymore :(

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanUlHaq, that's too bad! Rudix is useful but used to be more useful...